# cordova admob gives "No fill" error only if the app is installed from Google Play Store

Tags: google-play, admob, ionic4, cordova-admob

I have developed an app and integrated with Admob using cordova-admob-free. It works fine when the release apk is installed to any device (test or not). It also works when the app is installed to a test device from play store.

However, in any other device that installed the app from the Play Store, ads are not shown and LOAD_FAIL event fires with `error code: 3` and `reason: No fill`.

- My admob profile is complete. (I have an older app with working ads)
- I have the `<variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.0.0" />` dependency in the config.xml file. (I also tried the version 17.0.0)
- I created app-ads.txt in my developer website
- I tried to create new ad units and use them
- I didn't try to remove the app from the store and create another one as it takes too long to be confirmed.

I couldn't get any reply from the Admob support or github repo. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ads was working when installed from apk, I thought the case is different from newly published apps. However, it just begin to work after 8-10 days from publication. As the other "no fill" error cases, the solution was just waiting.